# Setting model user to current user when using inlineformset_factory in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I've hit a roadblock that I've spent hours trying to overcome, and I would appreciate some guidance.

I have two models: Listings and Addresses, with the following structure:

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Addresses)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)

class Addresses(models.Model):
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

I also have these:

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addresses
        fields = ['address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode']

class ListingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        fields = ['user']
```

I'm trying to create a form which will add a new listing, however the only information to be entered are the fields in the Addresses model. When the form is submitted, I need a new Listings object and a new Addresses object to be created, but the Listings object must have the 'user' foreign key equal to the id of the current logged-in user.

This is the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='share:login_view',          redirect_field_name='share:addlisting')
def addlisting(request):

    ListingInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Addresses, Listings, form=ListingForm, can_delete=False, extra=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        if address_form.is_valid():
            new_address = address_form.save()
            listing_formset = ListingInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=new_address)

            if listing_formset.is_valid():
                listing_formset.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/listing_added/'))

    else:
        address_form = AddressForm()
        listing_formset = ListingInlineFormSet()

    return render(request, 'share/addlisting.html', {
        "address_form": address_form,
        "listing_formset": listing_formset,
    })
```

In its current state, I get a form containing all the address fields, plus a drop-down user field. When the form is submitted, it creates a new listing with two foreign keys: one for the chosen user, and another for the new address that has just been created. This end result is what I want. HOWEVER, I don't want there to be a drop-down user field in the form - I need the user to be set to the current user. I tried using "exclude = ['user']" in the ListingForm class instead of "fields = ['user']", but this had the result of creating a new address without creating a listing to go with it. So all I got was a new address, and no listing.

What am I doing wrong? I would be so grateful for a solution to this, as I've been banging my head against a wall for a very long time!

Comment: I should have mentioned that the reason for including the ListingForm (rather than just having the AddressForm) is that I plan to include other fields on the form in due course (which will be part of the Listings object) - I just wanted to get the form structure in place first. I have reasons for wanting to keep the address separate from the listing, hence not putting the address in the listing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I wouldn't use a formset at all. If you need to collect user information to create the new listing, use a single `ListingForm` and `AddressForm`, save the new address, and then save the `ListingForm` with `commit=False`, assign the user and address to it, and then save the instance.

```
@login_required(login_url='share:login_view', redirect_field_name='share:addlisting')
def addlisting(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST, prefix="address")
        listing_form = ListingForm(request.POST, prefix="listing")
        if address_form.is_valid() and listing_form.is_valid():
            new_address = address_form.save()
            new_listing = listing_form.save(commit=False)
            new_listing.address = new_address
            new_listing.user = request.user
            new_listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/listing_added/'))
    else:
        address_form = AddressForm(prefix="address")
        listing_form = ListingForm(prefix="listing")
    return render(request, 'share/addlisting.html', {
        "address_form": address_form,
        "listing_form": listing_form
    })
```

If you ever have a many-to-many relationship on `Listings` you'll need to explicitly save those after saving the instance, as discussed here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I plan to add more fields to the listing form, and that I have reasons for wanting to keep the addresses in a separate table...

Comment: In that case, you'd want to omit the `user` field from the listing form and only specify the values you intend to collect from the user. Then use `listing_form.save(commit=False)` to instantiate the new listing in memory, set its user and address attributes (`new_listing.address = new_address; new_listing.user = request.user`), and only then save the new instance. Nothing in the above changes whether addresses are in a separate table.

Comment: If you're trying to use the formset to, say, show the user their current listings and add a new one, the above design should convert to a formset reasonably smoothly - I'd probably still keep user out of the form and explicitly set it on any changed instances, that's somewhat more controlled than using a hidden input widget.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. I just tried doing the following below the "if listing_formset.is_valid():" line in my original code: "new_listing = listing_formset.save(commit=False) \ new_listing.address = new_address \ new_listing.user = request.user \ new_listing.save()", but that's not working, so I think I've misunderstood. How should I be working this into the original code? (I assume I still need the inlineformset_factory, given that I'm altering two models.)

Comment: Well, if you're still using a formset you'll get a list of modified listings rather than a single one, so you'd want to iterate. Are you actually trying to edit the user's existing listings?

Comment: Ah, so that's why I'm getting the error "'list' object has no attribute 'address'"? At this point I'm just trying to enable a user to add a listing in the first place. (I hadn't got to the point of thinking about enabling them to edit a listing, though that is something that will need to be possible, so worth considering if it affects what I should do now).

Comment: If you want them to add exactly one listing, you don't need a formset at all - just a single form. For editing, one common pattern would be to have a non-editable list page that lets someone click into a specific listing to edit it - that's how the admin works by default, for instance. Presenting an editable list is certainly possible but it takes a little more work.

Comment: Even though I'm altering both the Listings and Addresses models? Perhaps that's one of the (many) things I've misunderstood. I thought that because I'm altering two models within one form, that I needed to use a formset. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Nope, you'd use two different forms (with a prefix argument if they have any overlapping field names). Formsets are for editing multiple instances of the same model. I'll edit in something demonstrating how to use multiple forms.

Comment: Great - your edited response did exactly what I was after, and thank you for taking the time to explain what was going on. Just so I understand correctly, would there only be reason to use formsets if I wanted to (in this case) create or edit multiple listings belonging to the same user, all in one go, as opposed to one at a time? I'm intending for each user to be able to click into (and edit) just one listing at a time, so it sounds as though I can avoid formsets completely.

Comment: Yes - formsets are useful for presenting editable lists of items, or creating new ones all at once, but aren't necessary if you're dealing with single instances. For instance, you might use a formset in a shopping cart style application to give a user a chance to review and edit multiple items in the cart prior to checkout. Or for another example, they're how the Django admin handles one-to-many relationships - when editing the "one" side of the relationship, the "many" instances can be shown with a formset. Given your plan to edit only one instance, you can avoid them.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper- I was going thru' the very interesting (and enlightening) conversation above. I am in a similar dilemma as Kate was in. In cases where e.g. I am intending to create a material BOM (a sub-assembly), where there would be one-to-many relationship between the sub-assy and the underlying materials (components/parts/sub-assys), I would need to use formset. So if I need to record if a new component has been added to the sub-assembly (of finished product or such) by a certain **user** how do I do that? My related query is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64753023/13823230) please.